# Query to obtain one graph in neo4j instead of two

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a graph in neo4j using the following query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///MyData.csv' AS row

MATCH (conta:Conta {nome: row.`Conta Origem`})
MATCH (contad:ContaD {nome: row.`Conta Destino`})
MERGE (conta)-[op:Movimentação]->(contad)
  ON CREATE SET op.Valor = toFloat(row.Valor), op.`Tipo de Gasto` = row.`Tipo de Gasto`, op.`Tipo de movimentacao`=row.`Tipo de movimentacao`;
```

And the output is:

[image: outcome]

But this is not exactly what I want since the output is showing two graphs with the node `1` not connected; I mean, what I want is nodes `10` and `11` being connected to the red-centered node `1`.

The problem is that they are representing transactions through bank accounts, and accounts 11 and 10 are origin accounts to account 1 which, in its turn, is an origin account for all the others.

How can I proceed and change the query so I can get it right? I am new to cypher, so I am sorry if it is obvious.

Edit: a sample of the data is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Please show us this file: MyData.csv.  It will give us the clue why nodes 10 and 11 are not connected to node 1.

Comment: Ok, sure. I edited the question with a sample of the data

Comment: Thanks. See my answer below. You can create more than label(s) to a node. For example; node1 can be Conta and ContaD nodes by creating label ContaD on node Conta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample csv file that you showed, the row on 2016-01-15 06:00:00 that has node 11 as origem and node 1 as destino was NOT connected because the match on :ContaD did not find node 1;

Let say;

```
line1: MATCH (conta:Conta {nome: row.`Conta Origem`})
line2: MATCH (contad:ContaD {nome: row.`Conta Destino`})
line3: MERGE (conta)-[op:Movimentação]->(contad)
  ON CREATE SET op.Valor = toFloat(row.Valor), op.`Tipo de Gasto` = row.`Tipo de Gasto`, op.`Tipo de movimentacao`=row.`Tipo de movimentacao`;
```

In line1; Conta is node11 which is okey and found

In line2; ContaD has no node1 so no rows returned

In line3; Skip this line since line2 is empty row and go to next row in excel

Thus node11 (a node Conta) will NOT be connected to node1 as a node ContaD.

Suggestion:
Why you need a label ContaD separated with Conta? You can create another label ContaD which contains the same nodes with Conta. The syntax to add another label to an existing node.

```
match (n:Conta) set n :ContaD
```

You might get an error now because ContaD is already created. Go back to your script when you created the nodes and edges and create the label ContaD together with Conta

Comment: I still don't get it, I think. Where would I point to `row.Conta Destino`? I was trying here but I am still getting the same graph.

Comment: You created two nodes Conta and ContaD where node1 belongs to Conta only and not in ContaD.  I suggest when you created your graph, you create a "LABEL" ContaD on top of Conta. It will make Conta and ContaD contains all nodes 1, 10 and 11 on the same place. Try this query:  MATCH (contad:ContaD {nome: "1"}) and you will get zero row. Then try MATCH (conta:Conta {nome: "1"}) and you will get one row.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. I used the multiple indexing labels like you suggested. It worked out perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please accept the answer. thanks.